# How do I search in search results

Tags: search, narrowing

When I `C-s` I can search. How should I do a function which I could bind for example to `C-r` which would let me search in the results of some predefined search query?

Like contents of window would be:

```
function xyz(a, b)
  return a + b
end
```

I can `C-M-s` with `function.*` as a query and the result will be `function xyz(a, b)`.

I want to have a function where I could enter a query and search in those results(which would be generated behind my eyes automatically).

**UPDATE**

Thank you all for the solutions. `occur`, `helm-occur` also works very well, but I have accepted Jordon Biondo answer because he provided the code I needed to answer my question fully.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your goal: it sounds like you want to implement some Lua-specific feature for `helm-swoop`, but your question (and especially the title) is not very clear on this.  Maybe I just didn't get your question because I'm not familiar with helm.

Comment: @paprika see updated question :)

Comment: isn't this exactly what helm-swoop already does?

Comment: @JordonBiondo I can see the function in helm-swoop list. But `imenu` worked great for me! Except I search for a generic solution to my question

Comment: Just wondering if you've considered "C-x c i" runs the command "helm-semantic-or-imenu", as you're already using helm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple approach would be to just use rgrep.

use <kbd>M-x</kbd>`rgrep` and specify searching for "function" in the current file in the current directory. You can wrap this up in a command so you don't have to specify the options each time like this:

```
(defun rgrep-lua-functions ()
  "run `rgrep` searching for 'function' in the current file."
  (interactive)
  (rgrep "function" (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) "."))
```

This will yield a searchable buffer with the function signatures and you can jump to the definitions if you want.

Comment: `grep`, `rgrep`, `occur`, and the like search only *line by line*. That is, the search contexts are single lines. I thought the OP was asking to search function definitions. But since this answer was accepted, I guess the question as posed is not really what was wanted.

Comment: in the question he specifies that he wants lines like `function xyz(a, b)` which, if your lua is formatted correctly is exactly what you'll get.

Comment: It's not clear to me. Yes, he does say he would be satisfied if such lines were found, to be searched. But in his example he shows the *whole function definition* as the "*contents of the window*" that he would want to be able to search. Single-line contexts do *not* present you with such content to be searched (whether in a "window" or otherwise). They present you with only the one line: `function xyz(a, b)`.

Answer (score 7):

Would `occur` work for you?

`M-x` `occur` or `M-s o` then entering your query will provide you with a list of lines matching that regexp.  You can then use `C-s` to search within the Occur buffer to refine your search within the matching lines.

Comment: Oops.  I spent so long writing up my answer that I didn't notice that someone beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs has a command called `occur` that is very well suited to this type of task.  If you have Helm installed, then you can use `helm-occur` instead.

---

### Occur

The `occur` command is part of vanilla emacs, and is bound to `M-s o` by default.  Occur will prompt you for a regexp to search for, and then it will open a new window showing all of the lines in the current buffer that contain a match.  The resulting `*Occur*` buffer is searchable using `isearch` (`C-s`).

- `M-s o function RET`  to show all lines matching "function"
- `C-x o` to move focus to the `*Occur*` buffer
- `C-s` to start a search within the search results

---

### Helm Occur

If you have helm installed you can use `helm-occur` to do something similar.  In this case, the `*Helm Occur*` buffer will not be directly searchable with `C-s`.  In Helm you can search for multiple search terms just by separating them with a space.

- `M-x helm-occur RET` to open a Helm Occur window
- `function` to show all lines containing "function"
- `SPC foo` to narrow the results to lines also containing foo

---

In either of these modes, selecting the match in the occur buffer and pressing enter will jump you to that line in the code.

Answer (score 3):

If you use library [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) then you can easily do this kind of thing. What you are asking for (if I understand correctly), is to *search only within certain* ***search contexts***.

For example, as in this case, you might want to search only within *function definitions* - the search contexts are function definitions. In Lisp, this would be things like `defun`s.

**Icicles** has several predefined [**Icicles** search commands](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) for searching **definitions** like this.  These are collectively called [**Icicles** Imenu commands](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Other_Search_Commands#IciclesImenu).

To search only command definitions, you can use command `icicle-imenu-command-full`.  To search only non-interactive function definitions, use command `icicle-imenu-non-interactive-function-full`.

Beyond searching definitions, you can easily define any kind of contexts to be searched. The simplest way is by providing a regexp. Command `icicle-search` prompts you for the search context-defining regexp. You can alternatively use a function to define the search contexts.

Other possibilities include:

- Searching the text of different kinds of THINGs (e.g., sexps, sentences, lists,
  strings, comments, XML elements,...), i.e., ignoring other text outside the THINGs.
- Searching zones of text that have given text or overlay properties, i.e., ignoring other text.

---

**NOTE:**

Other answers here that mention `occur` and similar (`helm-occur`) provide a limited kind of context searching:  the search contexts are just the **lines** of a buffer.

That is much more limited that, say, searching within whole function definitions, which is what I think you are asking for.  With **Icicles**, command `icicle-occur` (bound to `C-c '`) lets you search within lines as search contexts.

Answer (score 1):

With [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Isearch%2b):

1. **`C-M-s .+function.+`**, to search for whole lines that contain `function`.
2. **`C-z .`** followed by a regexp for something you want to look for in the lines that contain `function`.

(Optional) Repeat #2 with other patterns (regexps) to match in the same line.  The matches can be in any order within the line.

Instead of step #1, you can start with **`C-M-s .+ C-z . function`**.  The point is to search for whole lines that contain `function` along with any other patterns you like.

How **`C-z .`** works: It prompts you for an inline pattern to match (e.g. `function`).  It wraps that with `.*` on each side, to get a full-line pattern (e.g. `.*function.*`). It adds a filter predicate that requires that your current search string (`.+`) also match that pattern (e.g. `.*function.*`).

See [Dynamic Isearch Filtering](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicIsearchFiltering) for more information.